# How do I get particular ID in button value on selected dropdown in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am working with a form where I want to send email to a particular user
after form submission. There is one dropdown list where I can get
employee names. I will select any name from the list. On select particular
name, his email id or id should go into the value of the email button, so that
on click email, I will get his email id directly on the email button.

I am new to Angular. Please help.

```
<select ng-model="empInfo1" ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names4" class="span2"></select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="email()">Email</button>
```

Comment: where does your email details of the customer's available?

Comment: im fetching records here with names4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a ng-model and pass the model on ng-click, To get the selected email in button value , use angular expression

```
{{selected.email}}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.names4 = [{
      "candidate_name": "Thomas",
      "email": "tford0@noaa.gov",
      "id": "a35398ac-a974-47f6-9beb-ff9d5a6a8282"
    }, {
      "candidate_name": "Julie",
      "email": "jhansen1@pen.io",
      "id": "499e919a-e247-4665-9468-cc56a444848e"
    }, {
      "candidate_name": "Albert",
      "email": "amason2@g.co",
      "id": "76f53028-ec26-4b52-b12e-42ba3983ec36"
    }];
    $scope.email = function(selected) {
      alert(selected.email)
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <div class="col-md-20">
    <div id="main">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter List:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names4 ">
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="email(selected)">{{selected.email}}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are welocme :)

Answer (score 1):

If `names4` is the array which contains the `emp` name, and the email object like this:

```
[{candidate_name : 'xyz' , candidate_email : 'xyz@mail.com'},{...},{....}]
```

then in

```
<select ng-model="empInfo1" ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names4" class="span2"></select>
```

`{{empInfo1.candidate_email}}` will return the candidate email:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="email({{empInfo1.candidate_email}})">Email</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can keep your employee details in names4, like json below:

```
names = [{name:'A', empId: '100', email:'abc@gmail.com'}, {name:'b', empId: '101', email:'abc1@gmail.com'}];

<select ng-model="empInfo1" class="span2">
 <options ng-repeat="emp in names4" value="{{emp}}">{{names4.name}} </options>
</select>
```

in controller you can directly get ng-model value with employee id and email.

```
scope.email = function(){
  console.log(empInfo1)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: im calling it dynamically. and how to get email in button value.

Comment: couldn't understand your query. ng-click="email(empInfo1)" .Is this way  you needed?