# How to send email onclick button with email id in button value with angular?

Tags: angularjs, email

I am working on a project where i have to send email to particular user after form submit. I have one form that will fill by user and there is one dropdown where names of all users are display. on selected value of dropdown his email id will get on email button. means now i have his email id on email button.  So i want something like if i click on that email button email should be go to particular email id. I am new to angular so not enough idea about this logic please help me with the same. Below is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="email(selected)">Email To:{{selected.candidate_email}}</button>
```

From this script i get email id's.

```
$http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/finalCandidatesJson.php")
        .then(function(response)
        {$scope.names4 = $scope.names4 = response.data.service;});
        $scope.email = function(selected)
        {
        alert(selected.candidate_email)
        }
```

Comment: can you add more html code & email js function?

Comment: i just add this code to display email on EMAIL BUTTON  on select dropdown's particular user name

Comment: if i choose xyz from dropdown so his email id will get into email id xyz@mail.com

Comment: Can you add entire code? It's hard to tell with this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172382/how-do-i-get-particular-id-in-button-value-on-selected-dropdown-in-angular/42172894#42172894

Comment: in last question i mention this can u get from this ?

Comment: what to you want to do?

Comment: @Sajeetharan as  you know i got email with button . Now i want to send email on that email Id that i got with button

Comment: do you have a email service or you want to use gmail service?

Comment: @Sajeetharan  i have email service

Comment: call the email service with the id

Comment: @Sajeetharan ohk bro let me do. thanks for your response